# Ругается что объект возможно нулевой

Tags: angular

Создаю форму в компоненте

```
export class LoginPageComponent implements OnInit {

  form!: FormGroup

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      email: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      password: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]),
    })
  }

}
```

В html выполняю проверки ввода значений

```
<div *ngIf="form.get('email').touched && form.get('email').invalid" class="validation">
  <small *ngIf="form.get('email').errors.required">Enter Email</small>
  <small *ngIf="form.get('email').errors.email">Enter valid Email</small>
</div>
```

На каждую строку, где встречается form IDEA ругается

```
error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'
```

Я так понимаю, что это связано с тем что создание объекта происходит в ngOnInit.
Проставил везде знак "?" и IDEA перестает ругаться:

```
<div *ngIf="form.get('email')?.touched && form.get('email')?.invalid" class="validation">
  <small *ngIf="form.get('email')?.errors.required">Enter Email</small>
  <small *ngIf="form.get('email')?.errors.email">Enter valid Email</small>
</div>
```

Но на сколько это правильно?
Может есть более корректное решение этой проблемы?
Может я не правильно создаю объект FormGroup?

Answer (score 2):

Компилятор ругается на метод [form.get().](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup)

Согласно документации он возвращается или `AbstractControl | null`

Соответственно вы пытаетесь получить свойство `touched` следующим образом `form.get('email').touched`. Так как потенциально там может быть `null`, то свойство tuched получить невозможно.

Вариант с `optionalChaining` (знак вопроса после метода `get`), которым вы решили проблему - вполне нормальный способ.

И также можно вынести `form.get('email')` в геттер, как это сделано в [документации](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#creating-dynamic-forms)

```
get emailControl() {
  return this.profileForm.get('email') as AbstractControl;
}
```

Тогда в шаблоне можно будет писать так

```
<div *ngIf="emailControl?.touched && emailControl?.invalid" class="validation">
  <small *ngIf="emailControl?.errors.required">Enter Email</small>
  <small *ngIf="emailControl?.errors.email">Enter valid Email</small>
</div>
```

Comment: Но теперь компилятор ругается на emailControl?.errors.required
 error TS2533: Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'.
Это еще одни геттер надо создавать?

Comment: Возможно стоит добавить после errors тоже знак вопроса

Comment: А если errors действительно будет = null, как в этом случае отработает код в html? Не выскочит ошибка?

Comment: @alex если после errors поставить ? то ошибки не будет - элемент просто не отрисуется (если null)

Comment: Прочитайте про optionalChaining, по идее вернётся null, после чего он будет преобразован в false. И ваше условие выполнится корректно

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так:

```html
<div *ngIf="email" class="validation">
  <ng-container *ngIf="email.errors">
    <small *ngIf="email.errors.required">Enter Email</small>
    <small *ngIf="email.errors.email">Enter valid Email</small>
  <ng-container
</div>
```

ts:

```
get email() {
    const em = this.form.get('email');
    return em && em.touched && em.invalid ? em: null;
}
```

Comment: Такой код кажется не очень оптимальный, так как каждый раз придется высчитывать условие `em && em.touched && em.invalid`. Возможно обращение к `form.get('email')` потребуется без проверки этих условий. Ну или как минимум его можно сократить через `optionalChaninig`: `em?.touched && em?.invalid`.

Comment: @Sergey Glazirin https://blog.allegro.tech/2019/11/performance-of-javascript-optional-chaining.html

Comment: Во первых, этой статье 2 года, за это время браузерные оптимизации явно сделали лучше. Во-вторых, потери тут не большие будут, можно сказать, что ими можно принебречь. В-третьих, если правильно построить архитектуру компонента и и использовать еще onPush стратегию, то пересчеты будут редко происходить, что тоже не даст проблем с производительностью.